# How to Put an image and text overlapped when the TextView height is wrap content?

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I am working in an Android studio project. Here I am used an imageview and an TextView. I want to put some text on am image. 
There are different texts taken from a database. The size of the texts vary. 
The problem is when the size of the texts are too long it exceeds the size of the image, thus exceeds the image. The image size I have given is fixed. And the size of the TextView is wrap content.
Is there any way to make it possible that whatever the size of the texts, the image size will match accordingly? (I can use different images in case the size of the texts varies too much).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Mark the answer correct if it solved your problem. It will help other users who search for the same question in future and will also increase the reputation of the answerer.

Comment: Ya. Sorry I forgot to do it earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a relativeLayout to achieve the desired result. Make the imageView `alignLeft` and `alignRight` to the textView, so that it will match the width of the textView. Use `scaleType = "fitXY"` to fit the image `src` to the width of the imageView.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/text_view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/text_view"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text here" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants.

Comment: I can see the imageview is taking the required shape for each time. But the texts aren't showing anymore

Comment: @Zubayr I have edited the answer, with the order of views reversed. The text should be visible now.

Comment: @Zubayr Glad to help. Please mark the answer correct then.